# Defining instance variables using functions and instance methods in __init__

Tags: python, oop, instance

I have the defined the following class as:

```
def user_kitchen(handle):
    # return a BeautifulSoup object


class User(object):

    def __init__(self, handle):
        self.handle = str(handle)
        self.soup = user_kitchen(handle)
        self.details = self.find_details()

    def find_details(self):
        value_map = {}
        for detail, attribute in details_map:
            value = (self.soup).find_all(attrs=attribute)[0].text
            value_map[detail] = value
        return value_map
```

When I instantiate the class `User` as:

```
me = User('torvalds')
```

I am getting a `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

Here is the traceback:

```
In []: me = User('torvalds')
NameError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-f6d334f2ee24> in <module>()
----> 1 me = User('torvalds')

/home/user.py in __init__(self, handle)
     28         value_map = {}
     29         for detail, attribute in details_map:
---> 30             value = (self.soup).find_all(attrs=attribute)[0].text
     31             value_map[detail] = value
     32         return value_map

/home/user.py in _find_details(detail)
     18 
     19 
---> 20 class User(object):
     21 
     22     def __init__(self, handle):

NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

I have looked at few similar questions on SO about calling instance methods from `__init__` method:

- [Calling a class function inside of **init**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646326/calling-a-class-function-inside-of-init)
- [Python: How to define a variable in an **init** function with a class method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896957/python-how-to-define-a-variable-in-an-init-function-with-a-class-method)

Yet I am unable to fix this.

Comment: Please post full stack trace

Comment: @masnun Added it. Thanks for the siggestion :)

Comment: The lines in stack trace are not available in your code snippet. Will it be possible to post full code?

Comment: @masnun Added them as well

Comment: In your stack trace, I see this `/home/user.py in _find_details(detail)` - where is the `_find_details(detail)` method in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your stack trace, I see a method with the signature - `_find_details(detail)`. Inside that method, there's a line like - `value = (self.soup).find_all(attrs=attribute)[0].text`.

Your method doesn't take in `self` as the first parameter. So it can't find `self` in that context. Make it `_find_details(self, detail)` - then it should work.

Comment: Though your answer didn't help me solve my problem, I have accepted it due to your diligence and it is technically correct. :)